# in htaccess force https just if domain contains "-facebook"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

How to force HTTPs just if the domain contains `-facebook`?

I mean for example force HTTPs if domain is `demo-facebook.domainname.com`

Rewrite rule is this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

but I have problem with the `RewriteCond`

All rule conditions that I found are related to words inside the URL not in the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a `RewriteCond` using `HTTP_HOST` variable to compare a substring in domain name like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} -facebook\.domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: wow, works perfectly! sorry if i want restrict not just to "-facebook" but to "-facebook.domainname.com" ?